# pact: how to check a a field in the response that may or may not exist

Tags: python, pact

I have a service that will respond to a request with a json blob, such as this:

```
{
  "field1": 1,
  "field2": "2",
  "array": [1,2,3]
}
```

I know that I can test `array` by using `EachLike`, like this:

```
expected = {
  "field1": Like(1),
  "field2": Like("2"),
  "array": EachLike(1)
}
```

The issue is that "array" is an optional field in the response. It may not exist at all, and if it doesn't, I still need the contract to validate.  How do I define that a field in the response body must match a type if it exists, but that it may not exist at all?

Comment: How you tried https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema ? Probably, it may help.

Comment: @Fomalhaut nope, that doesn't help. It can be used to verify that a given JSON blob matches a schema, but the problem is I need something built into Pact that can be used to write the contract itself.  If you're not familiar with Pact, you probably need to read up on it to understand the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby/wiki/FAQ#why-is-there-no-support-for-specifying-optional-attributes

## Why is there no support for specifying optional attributes?

Firstly, it is assumed that you have control over the provider's data (and consumer's data) when doing the verification tests. If you don't, then maybe Pact is not the best tool for your situation.

Secondly, if you think about it, if Pact supports making an assertion that element $.body.name may be present in a response, then you write consumer code that can handle an optional $.body.name, but in fact, the provider gives $.body.firstname, no test will ever fail to tell you that you've made an incorrect assumption. Remember that a provider may return extra data without failing the contract, but it must provide at minimum the data you expect.

---

I would recommend that you write one interaction where you require that the array is populated, so that you know how to deal with a populated array. Then leave it out of the other interactions altogether, and then it won't matter whether it's populated or not.

Comment: thanks. If you have a chance, can you give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635547/pact-validate-that-an-array-contains-a-matching-hash) a look?